# How to interrupt a blocking call to UDP socket's receive()

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have a UDP server listening packets from a client.

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

while (isListen) {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
}
```

The `receive()` method will wait forever before a packet received. Is it possible to stop waiting for receiving? I can set a `boolean` `isListen` to stop the loop. On the other hand, if the socket is waiting then it will wait forever if no packet send from the client.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a socket timeout with the [setSoTimeout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) method and catch [`SocketTimeoutException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) thrown by the `socket`'s [`receive()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)) method when the timeout's been exceeded. After catching the exception you can keep using the socket for receiving packets. So utilizing the approach in a loop allows you to periodically (according to the timeout set) "interrupt" the `receive()` method call.

Note that **timeout must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation**.

An example (w.r.t your code):

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
socket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS)

while (isListen) {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length);

    while (true) {
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
            break;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            if (!isListen) {} // implement your business logic here
        }
    }
    // handle the packet received
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close the socket from another thread. The thread blocked in receive() will then throw an IOException.

```
while (isListen) {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length);
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        continue;
    }
}

void stopListening() { // Call me from some other thread
    isListen = false;
    socket.close();
}
```