# Sending and receiving multicast packets over wifi with 4G data connection active

Tags: android, udp, android-wifi, multicast, 4g

I know that the newest Android releases allow to automatically fall back data connection over 4G when the wifi network does not provide internet connectivity.

I would like to exploit this behavior in the following scenario:

1. An Android 8 smartphone is connected to a WiFi connection that is not wired to the internet
2. The smartphone is connected to the internet using a 4G data connection

I want my app to send and receive Multicast packets over the WiFi network. I tried the following:

```
    MulticastSocket clientSocket = new MulticastSocket(1900);
    clientSocket.setInterface(getFirstWiFiAddress()); // here I set the InetAddress of the Wifi card
    clientSocket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250"));
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket); // <--- Timeout Error (Only happens if 4G is enabled)
```

I can't understand why this error only happens when 4G is enabled. How can I overcome this problem?

Basically I need to trigger a wifi camera (it has its own wifi network where it broadcasts SSDP packets) while being connected to the internet.

Comment: Are you sure you can?  Lots of ISPs filter out multicast.  I would not be surprised if your wireless carrier did so.  In fact I'd be more surprised if they didn't.

Comment: I need to multicast only over wifi. Why does having a 4G connection active prevent me to multicast over the WiFi interface? What am I doing wrong? If I disable 4g data connectivity everything works fine.

Comment: You might increase [socket timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055466/3290339) or catch the exception and retry, if applicable.