# How to retry UDP packet request after wait time in android

Tags: java, android

I'm requesting data by sending a request command over UDP, and if it works, I'm supposed to receive a response. However, in the case that a response doesn't come through, I want to wait 3 seconds, then send a request again. I want to try this 3 times before "giving up" and displaying an error.

The code I have implemented is currently sending out the request once, but isn't sending it again one it realizes there is no response and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
int counter = 0;
static final int Limit = 3;

public void sendReq() {
new Thread((Runnable) () -> {
try {
    ...

    // Sending Request command here ...

    // Receiving
    while(true) {
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(dp);

        byte[] response = dp.getData();
        
        if(response.length == 0 || dp == null) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            if(counter == Limit) {
                // give up, display error
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(3000); // Wait 3 seconds
                sendReq();
            }
        } else {
            // Do stuff with response
        }

}
}
```

On the device I'm sending my command to, I made it so it holds its response on the first request, and I know the response isn't coming back. However my code isn't retrying.

What should I do?

Comment: `DatagramSocket.receive()` is a blocking call. I believe this is what you've experienced. Once the call is blocked, no retry can be performed. Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055466/3290339).

Comment: @Onik Hmm, it doesn't seem like it's working, I don't think the try block is firing.. would you know why? All I did was add the try block with the socket.receive and added the SoTimeout after my socket initialization

Comment: _"I don't think the try block is firing"_ This only means you get an exception before the new `try {}` block.